# Energy conditions for a "semi"-perfect fluid

Tags: general-relativity, fluid-dynamics, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

Consider the follwing diagonal stress-energy tensor with different values for the pressures:

$$
T_{MN}=\left(
\begin{matrix}
\rho & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0  &p_1   &0   &0  \\
0   &0  &p_2  &0  \\
0   &0   &0   &p_3
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

If all the pressures are equals ($p=p_1=p_2=p_3$), hence we have a perfect fluid where the energy conditions are imposed as:

The null energy condition: $\rho +p\geq 0.$ $\rho +p\geq 0.$

The weak energy condition: $\rho \geq 0,\;\;\rho +p\geq 0.$

The dominant energy condition:  $\rho \geq |p|.$

The strong energy condition: $\rho +p\geq 0,\;\;\rho +3p\geq 0.$

However, if ($p_1 \neq p_2 \neq p_3$). There is some way to rewrite these energy conditions?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. For example, the SEC can be written like this

$$ \rho + p_i \ge 0 \;\wedge \rho + \sum_{i=1}^{3}p_i \ge 0$$

as shown here: http://kodu.ut.ee/~manuel/teaching/2014_kv_gravity/lecture02.pdf.